# Не могу отправить письмо mail в PHP

Tags: php, apache

Вот мой код.

```
$mail=mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
if($mail){
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}else{
  echo "Mail sending failed."; 
}

?>
```

*.htacces* и *php.ini* пустые.

Я получаю ошибку

> "Mail sending failed.".

Что нужно добавить в эти 2 файла чтобы заработало?

```
    sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
```

Comment: а у вас стоит sendmail ?

Comment: @Darth, как проверить?

Comment: http://www.simplecoding.org/php-mail-pod-windows.html почитайте это

Comment: @Darth, инфа уже есть такая, как видите выше. Но надо же 465 установить да?

Comment: 1)добавьте в начало php `error_reporting(E_ALL);` 2) в php.ini `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"` [На этом мои полномочия всё](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOw-xqTLBzE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь postfix на машину, скорее всего отсутствует или стер:

```
sudo yum install postfix
sudo apt-get install postfix
```